# The linker does not find libraries in /lib

Tags: directory-structure, init, shared-library

I am building a small embedded system for a x86_64 target, with a Linux kernel and an initramfs which contains a dynamically linked busybox.

I tried to install the needed libraries (`libm.so.6`, `libc.so.6`) into `/lib` and the linker `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` into `/lib64`( because the busybox binary request it at this place).

```
lib
├── libc.so.6
└── libm.so.6
lib64
└── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

but it failed to link:

```
/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I managed to make it work by moving everything in `/lib64`:

```
lib64
├── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
├── libc.so.6
└── libm.so.6
```

or by creating a symlink between `/lib` and `/lib64`

```
lib
├── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
├── libc.so.6
└── libm.so.6
lib64 -> lib
```

But I still don't understand why the first configuration do not work. Why the linker is not able to find libraries in `/lib` ?

**EDIT:** To make it working properly (Thanks to yaegashi):

- Go into your initramfs root directory.
- Create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf` with the library path you need.

  `echo /lib > etc/ld.so.conf`
- Generate your `ld.so.cache` file.

  `ldconfig -r .`
- Re generate your initramfs. It's done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) of ld.so (the dynamic linker/loader).  The actual search paths are mainly determined by `/etc/ld.so.cache` (which is compiled from `/etc/ld.so.conf` by `ldconfig`) or built-in paths in your ld.so binary.  So check your platform configurations and how you built your glibc.

You can watch detailed activities of ld.so by running any binary with `LD_DEBUG=libs` set in the environment variable.

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs ls
     17441: find library=libselinux.so.1 [0]; searching
     17441:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     17441:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
     17441: 
     17441: find library=libacl.so.1 [0]; searching
     17441:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     17441:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1
     17441: 
     17441: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     17441:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     17441:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     ...
```

Comment: The `ld.so.cache` made it working and is the clean solution I expected. See my edit for the file creation steps.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, add `lib` to the shell environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` via .bashrc,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib
```

and then,

```
source /home/user/.bashrc
```

Comment: Inapplicable to OP's situation.  Do you ever run `/sbin/init` from a user shell?